# vertex attribute binding scope

Tags: opengl

The following code does not work:

```
self._program1 = glCreateProgram()
... attach shaders, link ...
glUseProgram(self._program1)
self._fooLoc = glGetAttribLocation(self._program1, 'foo')
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._fooBuffer)                    #!!!!!
glVertexAttribPointer(self._fooLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)  #!!!!!
glEnableVertexAttribArray(self._fooLoc)
glUseProgram(0)

... lots of stuff, but self._program1 is never used ...

glUseProgram(self._program1)
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
glUseProgram(0)
```

However, if I modify the code as follows, then it does work:

```
self._program1 = glCreateProgram()
... attach shaders, link ...
glUseProgram(self._program1)
self._fooLoc = glGetAttribLocation(self._program1, 'foo')
glEnableVertexAttribArray(self._fooLoc)
glUseProgram(0)

... lots of stuff, but self._program1 is never used ...

glUseProgram(self._program1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self._fooBuffer)                    #!!!!!
glVertexAttribPointer(self._fooLoc, 4, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)  #!!!!!  
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
glUseProgram(0)
```

Note that I have simply moved the two lines marked with exclamation marks.

What could the reason for this behavior be? I thought that if I associate an array buffer with a vertex attribute using `glVertexAttribPointer`, then that association becomes part of the state of the program and remains in force until it is changed explicitly?

Comment: Have you checked if there's any errors after each of the OpenGL calls?

Comment: @yiding There are no errors. (I'm using PyOpenGL which by default checks for errors after each OpenGL call, and throws an exception if there is an error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex Attribute <s>and Uniform</s> bindings are not associated with program in particular. The Attribute or Uniform location is just a number, and if a number of programs had identical location setups (as it can be explicitly done with later versions of GLSL), then the same attribute <s>and uniform bindings can be reused with several programs</s>. It also means, that glUseProgram does not restore bindings, that may have been altered somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks. But calls to `glUniform1f` etc and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` set state that is associated with a specific program, right?

Comment: @user763305: No. They just associate a number (pointer location, or numeric value) with a GPUs register location. The values of a Uniform or Vertex Attributes are set independent of the bound program and not tracked along with the program.

Comment: I ran some tests that seem to show that `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` change global state but `glUniform` change state that is associated with the used program. Also, at http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml it says "glUniform operates on the program object that was made part of current state by calling glUseProgram."

Comment: @user763305: Scratch what I wrote above regarding to uniforms. They are indeed retained per program object. Anyway your problem is related to attributes. Although it's good practice to set them whenever needed. It also sort of dimnishes the usefullness of explicit uniform locations.